# Square Connect API - Invoice not showing up

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, square, square-connect

I started developing with the Square Connect API and I am able to generate an invoice without any errors using the following code, yet the invoice never shows up when I log into the dashboard?

```
 var item = new CreateOrderRequestLineItem("Test 1", "1", new Money(100, Money.CurrencyEnum.CAD));

        var items = new List<CreateOrderRequestLineItem>()
        {
            item
        };

        CreateOrderRequest orderRequest = new CreateOrderRequest(NewIdempotencyKey(), null, items);

        OrdersApi ordersApi = new OrdersApi
        {
            Configuration = { AccessToken = AccessToken() }
        };

        try
        {
            var response = ordersApi.CreateOrder(LocationId(), orderRequest);
            var id = response.Order.Id;
            //result =  "Transaction complete\n" + response.ToJson();
        }
        catch (ApiException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Am I missing something here or should the invoice not show up? Basically I want my aspnet mvc web app to generate an invoice in Square that can be loaded and handled in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Orders API` creates an order that is meant to be attached to either a `Charge` or `CreateCheckout` endpoint. After that, the `order_id` would appear in the `Transaction` object (that can be retrieved either by `ListTransactions` or `RetrieveTransaction`).

If you do not pass the `order_id` to the `Charge` or `CreateCheckout` endpoints, it is only viewable by `BatchRetrieveOrders` endpoint.

Furthermore - this will not create an invoice (there is currently no Invoices API). The `Orders API` is intended to itemize your transactions. Without it, your transactions would just show "Custom Amount" in the dashboard, and would have no items associated with it. After creating an order, it is intended to be used immediately.

Reference:
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/orders-api-overview#how-to-use-it-the-orders-api-data-model

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-createorder

Comment: I see that now, thank you for the help. I guess this means there is no way for me to create an invoice/order in square that can be handled by another employee. We're building an repair ticket system and I wanted to have a square invoice generated automatically after the ticket was closed.

Comment: You could create the `order` at the time the ticket is closed (with the items and amounts, etc), and save the `order_id` off somewhere. Whenever the payment is ready to be made, pass the `order_id` either to the `Charge` or `CreateCheckout` endpoint, which will have all the items and amount to be paid still. If you require sending the "invoice" (quotes because no invoice API) to the buyer, then your best bet would be `CreateCheckout` that will give you a URL that you can give to the buyer to pay. Note this URL expires after 24 hours, so only use it when they're ready to pay.